# Не отображается "viewport" на странице. WP

Tags: wordpress, viewport

Не отображается 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
на странице результатов поиска. 
Сайт на Wordpress 4.6.1. Шаблон Impreza 3.4. На всех других страницах всё нормально.

Подскажите, как можно исправить и почему так происходит?

сайт http://my-moments.ru/

Comment: Надо поиском по файлам php выяснить, откуда meta выводится. Для вывода результатов поиска используется шаблон search.php. Возможно, ошибка в теме Impreza.